# I want to run gdb/gdbserver on MIPS32 router

Tags: gdb, mips, gdbserver

I have a router which is MIPS32, MSB. 
I want to run gdb/gdbserver on the router (RTL8198 core).

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : RTL8198
processor               : 0
cpu model               : 56322
BogoMIPS                : 498.07
tlb_entries             : 32
mips16 implemented      : yes
```

but, every gdb/gdbserver i found on Internet were failed to run with error messages, "not found", or "Illegal instruction"

As I know, "not found" message indicate that there is no library, 
so I checked library by readelf and tried to copy /lib in router.

but, in router, I can't mak a file in /lib because it's read only filesystem. 
I also tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it also failed.

```
# ls -al /var/lib
ls -al /var/lib
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            0 Aug  3 22:39 .
drwxr-xr-x   19 root     root            0 Aug  4 22:24 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       268731 Aug  3 22:39 ld.so.1
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      2767185 Aug  3 22:38 libc.so.6
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        42334 Aug  3 22:37 libdl.so.2
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            0 Aug  2 22:24 misc
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib
# ./gdbserver
./gdbserver
/bin/sh: ./gdbserver: not found
#
```

So, I tried to build myself. but i don't know how...
I can't solve lots of build errors.

is there anyone who can solve it? or
it there anyone who know the URL link of mips32 gdbserver for RTL8198?

Comment: Try using full path (e.g. `/foo/bar/gdbserver`). Also, try `ldd /foo/bar/gdbserver` to see if it can find the libs and/or where it wants them. `gdbserver` is a program [not a lib] and only needs some standard libs. Also, what about using JTAG for debug?

Comment: 1. what is the meaning of full path? I alreay tried with "/var/lib". is it not full path? 2. ldd is not in my busybox. 3. I dont have JTAG and I dont know how to use JTAG.. maybe I should study it.

Comment: Full path means "/var/lib/whatever" vs. being in /var/lib and doing ./whatever. JTAG is a hardware interface. Your chip supports EJTAG, which allows debug. Typically, you buy an inexpensive JTAG adapter that hooks up to your development system via USB and has a JTAG cable that connects to the JTAG interface/pins on your device [along with some software]. It is pretty standard for SoC systems to have the interface. The EJTAG can be used to facilitate the gdbserver connection. Google: EJTAG See: https://www.linux-mips.org/archives/linux-mips/2008-08/msg00156.html

Comment: even though I use JTAG, I should run gdbserver. right? but I can't run gdbserver now. that's the point of this question. I can't find any available gdbserver on my router and also I can't build available gdbserver. I downloaded and tried to build realtek sdk, rsdk, rtl819x toolchain, gdb source, ... but I failed in all ways.

Comment: EJTAG doesn't use gdb [AFAICT]. Also, RTL8198 is the realtek SoC, but not the router mfgr and model number. Are you using OpenWRT? I'd do `ls -R` and find out what files are available as well as any writable FSes or whether you can/should remount an R/O FS as R/W. What boot images (*.bin) images do you have? If you do something [bad] and brick the router, JTAG can reflash the device. You say your builds fail [IMO, a prereq], but don't say how/why. Also, _what_ do you want to debug [and _why_]? The answer will dictate what you need to do.

Comment: sorry for late reply and thank you for your reply. 1. I tried to build lots of toolchains and all trials were failed. each build has different fail msg so I can't write all fail msg. Maybe later, I will post other posts about it.

Comment: 2. I'm trying to exploit my router. I found a BOF bug at one of daemon in my router. I succeeded BOF exploit when I executed the daemon by "qemu-mips".But I failed at the router using same exploit code with segfault. So, I want to debug at the router. But I dont know how. This is what I want to do. I'm sure that I successfully jump to the shellcode at the router, because I executed "nc -l -p 1234" for connection from the router. And it was connected but the connection was closed right away. At that time, "segmentation fault" msg was up at the router.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "illegal instruction" because your router is not a full MIPS implementation, but its a Lexra, you can find more about it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220894/illegal-instruction-on-a-static-mips-binary)

Edit: Try [this gdbserver](https://mega.nz/#!IYYnCI7a!UGz1TALhySJJ0ZVmw6hegeIG5PunII-ILs1AHY4Fy1M)